# Eclipse Plugin - Listener for switch file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating currently an eclipse-plugin that has both an editor and a view, both shell display the same data from an EMF Model...
So now my wish is that everytime you change the opened file in the editor, the ViewPart refreshes, too... I have already in the init() function of my editor a call to a method of my view that refresh() its viewer...
Problem is just that init() is only called when you open the file. But when you have 2 or more files opened at the same time and you switch between them, init() is not called, so my view doesnt refresh...
Anybody a solution for that?

Best regards, Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the `setFocus()` method of your editor. It will be called each time a switch to an opened file occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much, didnt think that it is that easy!